# Would it be possible for supergiants to play football at the normal pace with a moon-sized ball in the right parallel universe?

Tags: gravity, electromagnetism, strong-force, weak-force

Imagine astronomical sized giants in a parallel universe where they could exist. They have moon-sized brains and are about 20 brains high. Their motion, in this universe, would be enormously slow. The kinetic energies involved are huge. So are their masses. If they use a flexible moon-sized ball it would take a long time to just kick the ball. Imagine they play on an infinite massive plane that has a (uniform) gravity field that's Earth-like.

There are parallel universes (assumption, say like the assumption made in the string landscape) where the coupling strength of the four forces are different from here. Would it be possible for the supergiants to play football in one of these parallel universes? Assume that also the speed of light is variable, as well as all other natural basic constants.

Comment: Hi Deschele. Your title Q is what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). With the exception of the trivial answer, "yes, it's your world, you set the rules," all answers are either opinion-based or story-based, which are both reasons to VTC. Your title Q is NOT the same as the post Q (VTC:Needs Focus), which is off-topic. From the [help/on-topic], questions "Must be specific and answerable, Must include context, [and] Must include restrictions/requirements."

Comment: Does the world 'moon' have a capital on it? There are many 'moons' of exceedingly varying sizes.

Comment: Physics of this world has to be very different, because those giants and their ball will have to collapse under their own gravity. The ball would vaporize when it's kicked.

Comment: @Alexander Cant you vary the coupling strength with the Higgs field or that of the gravitons?

Comment: @JBH Hi there! Im not sure if I set the rules. These universe are thought to exist in reality. In the string landscape.

Comment: Sure, if they can exist they can play it - why to ask?

Comment: @MolbOrg Well thats exactly the question. If they exist, could they play football? Football is a rather fast sport. The giants were created to live life very slowly. How can they play football in that huge inert form? Maybe by making them less massive or making the forces they have at hand bigger?

Comment: moon size ball is also not your typical football item - is it still counts as football? if yes, then so what if their game takes 100 years for the first half of it - ball won't move faster than you can kick or throw it - speeds are proportional to their capacities, so as to field/volume, they are playing in. idk why you ask, after the main handwavium everything is possible, if one accepts it then there is no reason to not accept anything that follows, nor there is anything that requires additional handwavium.

Comment: @MolbOrg I thought too to make it last 90 years instead of 90 minutes. Will their perception of time be different? Like a fly's perception of time is differrnt? Nice matrrials are used on this site! I already ssw unobtainium. Are there more? Like Notdonium? Or Impossibilium?

Comment: Perception of time can be any. You can imagine a regular little guy sitting in the brain pushing buttons, or millenias pushing with speed of high speed train. In essence there is nothing in your creatures, at least it not mentiont, which could connect them to reality and would allow to apply known science and such things. Not that such creatures could not be made with science (would be a stretch but) but sofar it seems you haven't descided at anything which constrains your choices. With equal probabilith they can end game in 3 seconds kicking ball with ligth speed and teleporting - you choose.

Comment: @MoldOrg Kicking the ball with lightspeed takes infinite energy. They obviously dont have infinite energy. Im assuming normal football.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Here on [worldbuilding.se], we ***only*** deal with fictional worlds of the OP's (your...) creation. We do not address questions concerning "real life" unless the question is specifically in the context of building said fictional world. If this really is a real-life question where you have no control over the rules of the world, then it's a question for [physics.se] and must be closed.

Comment: @JBH Do you consider super giants part of real life? Maybe football. Yes, thats part of real life.  In this case there is total control of the force strengths. Funny. Here Im told to go to physics, there Im told to go here.

Comment: @Otkin thanks for the edit. Im typing on phone. Some mistakes are inevitable. My laptop is dead and still must be lapped up. Natural I write as Natural because Nature is something I worship. But thats personal.

Comment: Please change my edit however you like. It is your query. I was just trying to correct a few spelling mistakes to make it easier to read.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I'm merely responding to your comment. `Im not sure if I set the rules. These universe are thought to exist in reality.` VTC:Opinion-Based because you won't assert the rules of your world, leaving the interpretation of the question open to too many opinions.

Comment: @JBC Im asking what rules should apply. These rules are different for all the 10exp500  different universes. If thats not how this site works then my question is indeed not justified. Can I ask for such rules? To make the world I built real?

Answer (score 1):

**They have gained the ability to control gravity and are now unaffected by it.**

Thanks to this mastery over natural forces they can ignore any size related problems like being crushed by their own gravity or planets being caught in their orbit and crashing into their face. They are even able to "fall" in the direction they want to go so they can move in space as they please. Depending on how powerful their anti gravity is, they may not even be bothered by black holes.

However kicking a planet like a football is problematic. Our earth for example could shatter into a million pieces if it were hit by a big enough asteroid. A cosmic giants feet, no thank you. On the other side it may just be that they need a denser planet to use as a ball. Or they could use their powers to strengthen the planets gravity so that it doesn't shatter when kicked.